# Characterization of provably recursive functions in PA

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, peano-axioms

This concerns Takeuti's Proof Theory: the book contains a lot of wonderful material, but the presentation is sometimes lacking (and so many typos!). At least that has been my experience so far, unfortunately. Well, the question concerns the proof of corollary 12.16:

> Suppose $R$ is a primitive recursive predicate and there is a proof of
>   $\to \exists x R(a, x)$ in $\text{PA}_k$ with ordinal $< \omega_k(l)$ for some
>   numbers $k$ and $1$ (as defined just above Definition 12.6). Then the
>   number-theoretic function $f$ defined by $$f(m) = \text{the least $n$
> > such that } R(m, n)$$
>
> is $<\!\cdot$-primitive recursive, where $<\!\cdot$ is the initial
>   segment of the standard ordering of $\epsilon_0$ of order type $\omega_k(l)$.

In the proof Takeuti claims

> We (temporarily) call a proof *reducible* if it is a proof in
>   $\text{PA}_k$, with ordinal $\omega_k(l)$ containing an essential cut
>   or ind, and with end-sequent satisfying [property] P [of Problem
>   12.11]. If $P$ [a proof] is reducible, **then by applying repeatedly the reduction procedure of Lemma 12.8** (modified for $\text{PA}_k$, as in
>   Remark 12.14), we obtain a proof in $\text{PA}_k$, of the same
>   sequent, without an essential cut or ind.

First of all very confusing that the symbol P is overloaded for an arbitrary proof and the property described in Problem 12.11. This is problem 12.11:

[image: Problem 12.11]

I highlighted two aspects of this problem that are confusing to me:

1. In my Dover edition the $\exists$ underlined in red is a $\forall$ (the screenshot is of the original first edition). What should it be?
2. Is the section highlighted with blue still part of the problem? Very confusing since Takeuti doesn't separate proofs, problems, and discussions very well.

**Now the main question:** Lemma 12.8 refers to the reduction part of Gentzen's (second) proof for the consistency of PA (if there is a proof of $\to$ then there is one with a smaller ordinal). But that doesn't in itself at all yield a proof of $\to \exists x R(a, x)$ that is without essential cuts and ind (induction). So presumably Takeuti intends to use Problem 12.11 (although he doesn't really say that), but I have no idea how that is proved... is my analysis of the situation correct? Did I understand Takeuti correct? Can you please show how to solve 12.11?

(Takeuti is so confusing sometimes... yes, I'm a little frustrated lol)

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that the red-underlined quantifier is intended to be existential. As for the blue-marked material, it doesn't seem to be part of the problem. I thought it might be a part of a hint for the problem, but that seems unlikely since there's an explicitly marked hint just before this material. So I'll guess that it's a continuation of whatever was happening before the problem, but here I won't claim to be reasonably confident.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I guess you are right about the quantifier, but it is strange that they changed it (erroneously apparently) between the first and second edition. You should expect such a typo to appear in the first edition only, or maybe in the first _and_ second edition. But only in the second? As for the blue-marked part, unfortunately I don't see how it connects to the previous material. Maybe it does, but I don't know (we just finished the proof of Gentzen that $\epsilon_0$ induction over PRA proves the consistency of PA; and those proofs have no logical inferences in the end-piece at all).

Comment: Would you know how to solve the Problem 12.11? Nevertheless, I appreciate your comment, thank you!